# Drawing a Pyramid within a Rectangular with Arrows and Text

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing

I want to draw a DIKW Hierarchy diagram exactly as is in the picture below:

[image: The Data-Information-Knowledge-Wisdom (DIKW) Hierarchy]

How can I do it with tikz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing this for entertainment :)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\setsansfont {texgyreheros}
  [
    Scale          = MatchUppercase ,
    UprightFont    = *-regular ,
    BoldFont       = *-bold ,
    ItalicFont     = *-italic ,
    BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic ,
  ]
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{MyTriangle}{RGB}{229,185,78}
\definecolor{MyArrow}{RGB}{84,106,160}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \draw[very thick, MyTriangle!40] (0,-0.03) -- (15,-0.03);
        \draw[very thick, MyTriangle!55] (0,-3) -- (15,-3);
        \draw[very thick, MyTriangle!70] (0,-6) -- (15,-6);
        \draw[very thick, MyTriangle!85] (0,-9) -- (15,-9);
        \draw[very thick, MyTriangle] (0,-11.95) -- (15,-11.95);
        \draw[very thick, MyTriangle] (15,-0.02) -- (15,-11.96);
        \draw[very thick,white,fill=MyTriangle!55] (0,0) -- (-8,-12) -- (8,-12);
        \filldraw[very thick,white,fill=MyTriangle!70] (0,0) -- (-6,-9) -- (6,-9);
        \filldraw[very thick,white,fill=MyTriangle!85] (0,0) -- (-4,-6) -- (4,-6);
        \filldraw[very thick,white,fill=MyTriangle] (0,0) -- (-2,-3) -- (2,-3);
        \node at (0,-2) {\bfseries\sffamily\scshape\LARGE Wisdom};
        \node at (0,-4.5) {\bfseries\sffamily\scshape\LARGE Knowledge};
        \node at (0,-7.5) {\bfseries\sffamily\scshape\LARGE Information};
        \node at (0,-10.5) {\bfseries\sffamily\scshape\LARGE Data};
        \node[text width=8cm] at (7,-2) {\Large $\bullet$ understanding, intergrated, actionable};
        \node[text width=8cm] at (9,-4.5) {\Large $\bullet$ contextual, synthesized, learning};
        \node[text width=8cm] at (11,-7.5) {\Large $\bullet$ useful, organized, structured};
        \node[text width=8cm] at (13,-10.5) {\Large $\bullet$ signals, know nothing};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-3.7cm,yshift=-3cm]
        \draw[-{Triangle[width=18pt,length=12pt]}, line width=8pt, rounded corners=25pt, MyArrow] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (2,1);
        \node[text width=5cm] at (1,-.5) {\Large given insight,\\becomes};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-5.7cm,yshift=-5.5cm]
        \draw[-{Triangle[width=18pt,length=12pt]}, line width=8pt, rounded corners=25pt, MyArrow] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (2,1);
        \node[text width=5cm] at (1,-.5) {\Large given meaning,\\becomes};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-7.7cm,yshift=-8.5cm]
        \draw[-{Triangle[width=18pt,length=12pt]}, line width=8pt, rounded corners=25pt, MyArrow] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (2,1);
        \node[text width=5cm] at (1,-.5) {\Large given context,\\becomes};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]